# Check column if filled cell thenin other sheet search and paste the filled cell in the specific row

Tags: excel, vba

I need some assistance from you. Have 2 sheets, named Sheet1 and Sheet2. In sheet2 in column C from C5 to end i could enter some text or date. Then i need from the same sheet, Sheet2 to find corresponding data from the cells A and B in the filled row with cells from columns E and  and B in Sheet 1. Then to paste the entered text or date from Sheet2 to column F in sheet1 on the corresponding found row.
Here is the code i have so far but it works only for row 5 from Sheet2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet, Rng As Range, r As Range
Dim bCellsFilled As Boolean
Set sht = ActiveSheet
Set Rng = sht.Range(sht.Range("C5"), sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
bCellsFilled = True

For Each r In Rng
    If r.Value = "" Then
        bCellsFilled = False
    End If
Next r

If bCellsFilled = True Then
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Value Then
  If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B5").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value Then
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F5") 'Copy Then
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").ClearContents
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").ClearContents
 End If
 End If
End If
```

Thanks very much for the comments

Comment: 1.  There is no question, or statement of where the code if failing, we have no idea how to help.  2.  sounds like a simple VLOOKUP() function will do what you want.

Comment: I can't define to look range in sheet1 not only a specific cell, Code is working but only for entries in Sheet2 row 5, not for other rows

Comment: You will need to implement a loop, google `For Loop Range vba` you will get a lot of examples.